# Image size validation (GUI extension)

Tags: gui-extensions

I'm trying to add an image size validation using a Tridion extension in the Save component event.

My js code is working but there is a problem, the first time that I add the image the validation doesn't work because the image is not already loaded properly. The first time I try to save the component the console.log shows `height: 0` and `width:0`, despite the image src is the correct... (and height should be 20)

I think that is a usual problem with image loads and js, but the solutions i've tried are not working.  Some idea?

The code:

```js
...
var uriImagen = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder
                    .getField("preguntas").getField("imagen").getValues();
if (uriImagen != null) {
    var img = new Image();
    var cadenaImagen =  $display.getMultimediaHandlerPath() + "?URI=" + uriImagen;
    img.src = cadenaImagen;         
    img.load = function(){
        console.log("height:"+img.height);
        console.log("widtht:"+img.width);
        //image size validation
        if (img.width != 20 || img.height != 20 )
        {
        alert("wrong image size: must be 20x20px");
        return true
        }
    };
    // handle failure
    img.onerror = function(){
        console.log("image error");
    };

...
```

Comment: You might be experiencing what is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3016076/209103. The image has loaded, but not yet been added to the document (so its size hasn't yet been determined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why doing it with a GUI extension? it would be faster and easier to do it with an Event System - Initiated Phase, you can easily throw an exception indicating that the image size is incorrect.

Comment: +1 to the Event system for [validation on save](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html), especially for images. A [GUI extension might fit better for text field validation](http://www.curlette.com/?p=913). Resizing can happen in templating as well.